# Angular animation not triggering when state is changed in the 'closing' event of the mat-sidenav component?

Tags: angular

I would like to animate how the side nav links get displayed in the side nav menu. I would like them to come sliding in from the right. To get the state to change I listen for two events on the side nav. When it starts opening I invoke a call back that toggles the state, and the same thing happens when the side nav is starting to close. I can achieve this with the following code:

component.ts:

```
`
@Component({...})
sideNavAnimationState: string = 'out';
...
sideNavOpened(){
    console.log("SidenNavOpen")
    this.sideNavAnimationState = this.sideNavAnimationState === 'in' ? 'out' : 'in';
  }

  sideNavClosed(){
    console.log("SidenNavClose")
    this.sideNavAnimationState = this.sideNavAnimationState === 'in' ? 'out' : 'in';
  }
`
```

component.html:

```
`
<mat-nav-list [@sideNavLink]="sideNavAnimationState">
    <a mat-list-item href="">Merchandise</a>
    <a mat-list-item href="">Gallery</a>
</mat-nav-list>
`
```

The following animations only work when the side nav is opened. It does NOT get triggered when it is closed:

```
`
animations: [
    trigger('sideNavLink', [
      transition('out => in', [
        query('a', [
          style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
          stagger(250, [
            animate('.3s cubic-bezier(.52,-0.21,.29,1.26)', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)'}))
          ])
        ])
      ]),
      transition('in => out', [
        query('a', [
          style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' }),
          stagger(250, [
            animate('.3s cubic-bezier(.52,-0.21,.29,1.26)', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-3%)'}))
          ])
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
`
```

I dont understand why. As it goes from one state to another and it should be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't get triggered?
I copied your code and it seem to work but you are missing something like

```
      state('out', style({ opacity: 0 }))
```

in your animation. Without this, the opacity will switch back to 1 after the out animation is finished. (what may let you think out animation doesn't get triggered)

Comment: After researching this some more, i think it turns out that you cannot override default animations set by angular material components. When the side nav component is in the 'closing' state, it has its own animations that get triggered when I looked in source code. There is currently no way to override those or change the timing.

Answer (score 0):

Researching this topic a bit more. It turns out that currently you cannot control the animations set forth by the angular components. I found a github ticket that is requesting this functionality albeit for dialogs but I believe it would apply to any angular material components to allow developers to override default animations.

[Github ticket](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8857)